# Login on web with firebase authentication function "signInWithEmailAndPassword" fail after deployment on firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to develop an web-app but remains stuck on the login. When I test the program on the localhost the login function works perfectly and navigate to the page that I expected. The main issue occurs after the deployment with firebase web hosting. When I deploy the web with firebase web hosting and test it, the login navigates back to the login page without any errors being displayed.
Note that I have already done the following:

- set up the support email
- Use the domain xxx.firebaseapp.com
- enable the authentication option for email/password as "enabled"

Backend - node.js
Frontend- plain html and css
The system login is implemented as follow:

login.js

```
let loginForm = document.getElementById("login");

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    const login = event.target.username.value;
    const password = event.target.password.value;
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, password)
    .then(({ user }) => {
        return user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
          return fetch("/sessionLogin", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "CSRF-Token": token,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ idToken }),
          });
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return firebase.auth().signOut();
      })
      .then(() => {
        window.location.assign("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
    return false;
});
```

login.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Geographic Research - Login</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrfToken}}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-app.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-auth.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js" defer ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main> 
        <section>
            <form id="login">
                <center> <h1> Login </h1> </center>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <input type="password" name="password" minlength="8" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">    
                    <button onclick= "window.location.href='/signup';" class="signup btn"> Sign Up </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        
        <script defer src="/js/firebase_init.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/js/login.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
// List of dependencies used in the code
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const csrf = require('csurf');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

// Module handling on csv file and file system
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

// Module working on file uploads
const formidable = require("formidable");

var hbs = require('handlebars');
var engines = require('consolidate');

const path = require('path');

// Initialize firebase application
var serviceAccount = require('./service_account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://sadao-f4a1e.firebaseio.com"
});
const app = express();
const csrfMiddleware = csrf({cookie: true});

app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views/"));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrfMiddleware);

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
    res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
    next();
})

const db = admin.database();


// API handling Authentication , Login, Logout
app.get('/login', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

app.get('/signup', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('registration');
});

app.post("/sessionLogin", (req, res) => {
    const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();

    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;

    admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn}).then(
        (sessionCookie) => {
            const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true};
            res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
            res.end(JSON.stringify({status:"success"}));
        },
        (error) => {
            res.status(401).send("UNAUTHORISED REQUEST");
        }
    );
});
```

I really need help on this! Can anybody please help me out ;(

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try here:

1. Do not use form to submit your password, simply use input. Firebase submits the password and email by themselves with the functions.
2. In your Firebase console, under the authentication => sign-in method section, if you scroll below, make sure that you have the `authorized domains` of the domain where you are deploying your app enabled.